# is there such a thing as a negative techum?

Tags: halacha, eruv-chatzerot, eruv-techumin

Can a neighborhood in a city form a negative eruv techum so one would then need to intentionally make a techum to get into it?

Can it be done with an eruv chatzerot?

Comment: Why would you expect that to be possible? Why would anyone want to do that?

Comment: @Double the neighbors have troublesome kids:)

Comment: @user6591 you mean ones getting drunk and beating up people in the other city? :)

Comment: Please explain how the negative eruv chatzerot would work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The [Mishna in the Gemoro Eruvin 81b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=81b&format=text) that you cannot make a (positive) eruv techumim for another person without his knowledge because he loses something from it (viz. the ability to walk in in the opposite direction to the Eruv) as Rashi says

> חוב הוא לו שמפסיד לצד האחר ושמא אינו נוח לו:

I infer that all the more so, one cannot make your postulated "negative eruv techum".